# How do I colour code cells based on inputs? Found a code but do not understand the "how"

Tags: excel, vba

I need to colour code cells based on what is in that cell.

- Hard-coded numbers: blue
- Another worksheet reference: green
- Formulas: black

```
Sub mcrFinancial_Color_Codes()
    Dim rng As Range
    Dim rErr As Range

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each rng In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Selection)
        If rng.HasFormula Then
            Set rErr = Range(Mid(rng.Formula, 2, Len(rng.Formula) - 1)) 'Somehow sees if formula references another sheet???
            If CBool(Err) Then
                rng.Font.ColorIndex = 1 'black
            Else
                rng.Font.ColorIndex = 10 'green
            End If
            Err = 0
        ElseIf CBool(rng.Value) Then
            rng.Font.ColorIndex = 5 'blue
        Else
            rng.Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic 'default
        End If
    Next rng
    Set rErr = Nothing
End Sub
```

I found this code but I don't understand some things after `If rng.HasFormula`

1) What does the `Set rErr` do and how does it differentiate formulas with cell references that contain an exclamation mark (!).

2) `rErr` is a variable but is not actually referenced except in `Err`. Does the r represent something?

3) `If CBool(Err)`. This somehow returns true for Err and labels it black, green otherwise. How does it get the boolean from Err?

Comment: 1: this statement assigns something to the `rErr` (range) object. `Set` is required for assigning to object variables. 2) `rErr` *is* referenced in the preceding line. `Err` is **NOT** referencing `rErr` and the "r" doesn't represent something on its own, it's part of the variable name for `rErr`. `Err` is the implicit/global Error object in VBA. `rErr` is just a Range that happens to have a similar name. 3) `CBool` is a conversion function that attempts to cast a value to a boolean. A more typical use case is to test whether `Err.Number = 0` (no error).

Comment: I really like the `rErr` line, it's hilarious.

Comment: I don't understand how the CBool(Err) equals 1 or more.

Comment: @Julian It doesn't. Output of the `CBool()` is either `True` or `False`. If you mean `Err` itself then `Err.Number` simply prints the number of an error. For example, if an error occured due to *Overflow*, then `Err = 6` (or `Err.Number = 6`).

Comment: @Julian `Err` is the VBA error object. Its default property is `.Number`, so `Err` is equivalent to (but less obvious than) `Err.Number`. `CBool()` is the VBA function that converts an `Integer` to a `Boolean`. In VBA `0` = `False` and anything else = `True`. Hence `CBool(Err)` is the equivalent of `If Err.Number = 0 Then`. It's much shorter to use `CBool()` and, once you understand it, more clear.

Comment: @AntiDrondert yes I understand what Err and CBool does now. But what I don't understand is how the `Set rErr` line and the `CBool(Err)` line interact with one another (if they do at all) to increase Error incrementally by 1. I'm learning Python as well so I don't know if the syntax is roughly the same.

Comment: @Julian Take the following example: `Set rErr = Range("Sheet!$A$1")`, *"Sheet1!$A$1"* here is a valid address, so no error occurs, therefore `Err.Number = 0` and `CBool(Err) = False`. `Set rErr = Range("#$%^Y")` is not valid, editor will throw a run-time error, hence `Err.Number <> 0` and `CBool(Err) = True`.

Comment: @AntiDrondert That makes sense. But in this case, both the black and green cells have formulas. It's just that the green cells reference another worksheet so it is "Sheet!$A$1" whereas black only has "$A$1". How does referencing the same spreadsheet result in an error if the formula is valid (resulting in black highlighting)?

Answer (score 1):

### This procedure works via error handling

```
Mid(rng.Formula, 2, Len(rng.Formula) - 1)
```

This part pulls an address from a formula in a cell, for example if you had formula `=Sheet1!$A$1` it will retrieve `Sheet1!$A$1` which is a range address.

```
Set rErr = Range(Mid(rng.Formula, 2, Len(rng.Formula) - 1))
```

Here we set range with retrieved address. Usualy if address is invalid VBA Editor would throw an error, but with [On Error Resume Next](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/on-error-statement) which can be used to disable an error-handling routine, we intentionaly ignore this error and procedure doesn't stop.

[Err Object](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/err-object) contains information about run-time errors. The default property of a `Err` is `.Number` which specifies the run-time error. If no error occured (in this case, address was valid) `Err.Number = 0` or `Err = 0`, otherwise it is more than zero.

```
CBool(Err)
```

[CBool](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/concepts/getting-started/type-conversion-functions) is a type conversion function. It converts 0 to FALSE and any other number to TRUE. If Error occured, it's number will be more than 0 = > `CBool(Err) = True`

`r` in `rErr` most likely stands for `Range`, but this is just speculation.

---

### You can try something like this, though it is still clumsy:

```
Sub mcrFinancial_Color_Codes()

    Dim LoopCell As Range
    Dim Checker As Range

    For Each LoopCell In Intersect(ActiveSheet.UsedRange, Selection)
        With LoopCell
            Select Case True
                Case .HasFormula
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set Checker = Range(Mid(rng.Formula, 2, Len(rng.Formula) - 1))
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    If Checker Is Nothing Then
                        .Font.ColorIndex = 1
                    Else
                        .Font.ColorIndex = 10
                    End If

                Case .Value <> 0
                    .Font.ColorIndex = 5

                Case Else
                    .Font.ColorIndex = xlAutomatic
            End Select
        End With
    Next LoopCell

End Sub
```

Comment: In other words, this bit of code horribly abuses a lot of good coding principles that ends up making it difficult to follow. `OERN` applies to the whole proc so _all_ errors are ignored. Using the default `.Number` property of `Err` obscures the code making it difficult to read. `rErr` is misused Hungarian Notation and [should be shot on sight](https://www.joelonsoftware.com/2005/05/11/making-wrong-code-look-wrong/).

Comment: So I should use another code? I just found this on the Microsoft forum.

Comment: @FreeMan This pretty much sums it up, yeah. There are multiple uses for `OERN` in VBA (these look clumsy most of the time, but sometimes are necessary) but this is not the case.

Comment: @Julian - you should understand the implications of the code you're using (which you're attempting to do) instead of blindly copy/pasting. `OERN` has some valuable, valid uses - almost(?) all of them involve wrapping a _single_ line of code where you'd expect an error, but want to continue because you're going to handle it inline (like the `Set rErr =...` line). Wrapping a whole procedure in it will lead to future [SO] questions because your code will be broken in other ways but the error is swept under the rug by `OERN`.

Comment: @Julian Read the link to understand the issues with HN - it's a simple fix in this code and won't require you to chuck it at all, just make some minor adjustments. [Rubberduck](http://www.rubberduckvba.com/) is a great add-in for the VBE that will help you find **and fix** these types of "gotchas" and will help you considerably as a new VBA programmer. (I'm a fan & constant user, and have made some minor contributions to the open-source project.)